# To clarify the entropy/ energy/ Gibbs Eqs

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, entropy

Both case are isothermal and internally reversible processes.
Why is it wrong to use energy conservation in case7-24 to solve the problem?

I referred to the textbook (Aqueous tea An Engineering Approach, 5th Edition) CH7-7 and used Gibbs equation to solve case7-24.
The correct answer could be obtained, but
$Q_{intrev}=0 $. Unlike $Q_{out} =W_{pwin}=200^{KJ}$, where energy is conserved, please say something why this is so.
(Thank you for your time and consideration.)

[Ref. Gibbs Eqs](https://upload.cc/i1/2022/05/22/iSzWXv.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/709947/2451

Answer (score 3):

**Initial State:**
$$T_1=313\ K$$$$V_1=V$$$$n_1=n$$$$P_1=\frac{n_1RT_1}{V_1}=\frac{nR(313)}{V}$$

**Final State:**$$T_2=313\ K$$$$V_2=V$$$$n_2=n$$$$P_2=\frac{n_2RT_2}{V_2}=\frac{nR(313)}{V}$$

The final state is identical to the initial state, so $\Delta S=0$

Let's check to make sure that the system satisfies the 2nd law of thermodynamics.  For this to be the case, we must have that $$\Delta S\geq \frac{Q}{T_S}$$where Q is the heat transferred from the surroundings to the system and $T_S$ is the temperature at the interface between the system and surroundings ($T_S=303\ K$).  For this process, $\Delta U=0$ and $Q=W=-200\ kJ$.  So we have $$\frac{Q}{T_S}=\frac{-200000}{303}=-660\ J/K$$The entropy change (zero) is greater than this, so the 2nd law is satisfied.

Comment: Please help me to understand why $Q_{intrev}=0$ , not $Q_{intrev}=W_{pwin}=200^{KJ} $ in case7-24  energy balance.

Comment: In determining the entropy change for an irreversible process, you need to devise an alternate  reversible path between the initial and final states and calculate the integral o dQ/T for that alternative path.  The alternative path does not have to bear any resemblance whatsoever to the actual irreversible path in terms of the amount of heat transferred and the amount of work done.  In this case, the initial and final states are identical, so the reversible path can be taken as the null path; but other alternative reversible paths willl give the same zero change in entropy.

Comment: Very clear answer, thank you for your help. ^^